# Starting multiple batch files at the same time

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a project using the Torque Engine 1.2 (mostly irrelevant but anyway...)

I have a batch file, in which I want to run my 'master server' and my 'dedicated' server. I can have two seperate batch files running each seperately, however I'd much rather just do it from one. I have tried using 'call' but this runs the first server (master) and on closing this server, THEN it starts the dedicated one. I need both to be run at the same time from one file. First I guess, is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing so? Below are the two lines of code I need to run, from one file and at the same time.

```
call "Project.exe" -dedicated -master -mission levels\Mountains.mis
```

and

```
call "Project.exe" -dedicated -mission levels\GrimwoodPass.mis
```

Starting a server opens another batch/server window in which I can enter commands and such. Could this be the reason I can't have two started at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `start` instead of `call`.

E.g.:

```
start "" "Project.exe" -dedicated -master -mission levels\Mountains.mis
```

The first parameter to the start command is the window title.

Comment: when i use start, it doesnt start my server. here is an image of what i seee. Not too sure how to explain it...

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/403/75999419.png/

Comment: the "" is the title of the command you are sending, "" just leaves it empty, but it seems even an empty title is good enough for start to work properly.