# Run multiple batch files from one master batch

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple batch files. Each batch file opens an exe file and run a command. The command compiles the results in csv format. This all works like heaven.

I am trying to create a master batch which could run each of the batch file one by one.
The individual batch file names are as 1.bat, 2.bat . . . .32.bat

I tried,

```
Call 1.bat
Call 2.bat
.
.
.
Call 32.bat
```

but it is only running the first command...

I also tried without call, same result.

I am using the following code in each batch file:

`Start /D "C:\test 2\" CSC.exe "1.lq"`

`Start /D "C:\test 2\" CSC.exe "2.lq"`

and so on

Can anyone help me crack this?

All I want My master bat to run first batch, on completion run second and so on so forth.

Hope it makes sense.

I really appreciate your help on this guys.

Shei

Comment: can you show us the contents of some of the BAT files? it's probably something related with a secondary BAT being invoked or the current directory being changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running multiple batch files from a single batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154893/running-multiple-batch-files-from-a-single-batch-file) and [Can't run multiple batch files sequentially from master batch in Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17903609/62576)

Comment: Continuing PA's theme - Or the problem could be an EXIT in your 1.bat. You want EXIT /B, not EXIT.

Comment: @KenWhite It's not a duplicate as he obviously implemented the accepted solution from that question, but encountered issues with it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Then the poster needs to provide more information that makes it different from those questions. Without more details, they're the same question.

Comment: You need to use `start /wait` if you want the batch files to wait for the external commands to complete: `start /d "C:\test 2" /wait csc.exe "1.lq"`. If that doesn't help, try with just 2 or 3 child scripts, and add `echo` statements with a running number at beginning and end of each child script, so you can see at which point things stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Try like  this:-

```
START /WAIT  batch1.bat
START /WAIT batch2.bat
```

Comment: It runs the first batch, closes the window and than leave other windows hanging and do nothing, I am afraid.

Comment: @Shei7141 Then you need to show the code of (some of) the child batch files as *PA.* requested.

Comment: @Shei7141 Please update your question with that code. It's likely to go unnoticed by others if you post it in a comment to an answer.

Comment: @Shei7141:- I think you need to move the START /W command and put it in every batch file in front of (every) command that that batch file executes and doesn't wait for the termination of.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and change the code to Start W "C:\test 2\" ccs.exe "runMe.lq". But I am getting an err now. . . . Please help

Comment: I also tried Start W start /d "C:\test 2\" ccs.exe "runMe.lq". but same happened . . .

Comment: How about Start /W "C:\test 2\" ccs.exe "runMe.lq"??

Comment: Did you checked this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903609/cant-run-multiple-batch-files-sequentially-from-master-batch-file-in-win7 ???

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321977/starting-multiple-batch-files-at-the-same-time ?/

Comment: And this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187938/run-batch-files-sequentially ??

Comment: Thanks Rahul,
I saw and tried the provided links but still same thing is happennig. If I use start, or start wait, it is runing the first bat and leaves the other windows opened. If I use call it is just calling first bat and that is it.....

Comment: @Shei7141 Please don't shout. We're not deaf. And please refrain from flooding an answer with comments. This is not a chat.

Comment: My apologies, I didnt mean to shout or anything.... I'll try to find my answer else where.... THANKS A MILLION FOR YOUR ASSISTANCE>... really really appreciate it. Bye :)

Comment: @Shei7141 I suggested a troubleshooting approach in my last comment to your question. Did you follow these instructions? What were the results?